# Google Sheets Formula to refine data of a column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is there any formula to extract a website from a cell value in google sheets
[convert value from 1st column to as shown in 2nd column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSBWx.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regex` to retrieve string with pattern like website:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(G1,"[a-zA-z]+\.[a-zA-z]+\.?[a-zA-z]+")
```

[image]

#### Reference:

- [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IFERROR(IF(ISURL(SPLIT(A1:A, " ")), SPLIT(A1:A, " "), ))),,9^9))))
```

[image]